# Error: Duplicate symbol error in c

Tags: c

I am succesfully able to  use the same file in my **Visual Studio project** but when i tried to compile in a **micro controller specific SDK**. Its giving me error:

```
Duplicate symbol "key" in "C:\WorkSpace\code.obj
```

In my code i have key only at 2 places and they seems clearly independent, this is a header file and i am sure i included this only once.

```
//sha256.h
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h>
#define uchar unsigned char // 8-bit byte
#define uint unsigned int // 32-bit word

typedef struct {
   uchar data[64];
   uint datalen;
   uint bitlen[2];
   uint state[8];
} SHA256_CTX;

uint key[64] = {
   0x428a2f98,0x71374491,0xb5c0fbcf,0xe9b5dba5,0x3956c25b,0x59f111f1,0x923f82a4,0xab1c5ed5,
   0xd807aa98,0x12835b01,0x243185be,0x550c7dc3,0x72be5d74,0x80deb1fe,0x9bdc06a7,0xc19bf174,
   0xe49b69c1,0xefbe4786,0x0fc19dc6,0x240ca1cc,0x2de92c6f,0x4a7484aa,0x5cb0a9dc,0x76f988da,
   0x983e5152,0xa831c66d,0xb00327c8,0xbf597fc7,0xc6e00bf3,0xd5a79147,0x06ca6351,0x14292967,
   0x27b70a85,0x2e1b2138,0x4d2c6dfc,0x53380d13,0x650a7354,0x766a0abb,0x81c2c92e,0x92722c85,
   0xa2bfe8a1,0xa81a664b,0xc24b8b70,0xc76c51a3,0xd192e819,0xd6990624,0xf40e3585,0x106aa070,
   0x19a4c116,0x1e376c08,0x2748774c,0x34b0bcb5,0x391c0cb3,0x4ed8aa4a,0x5b9cca4f,0x682e6ff3,
   0x748f82ee,0x78a5636f,0x84c87814,0x8cc70208,0x90befffa,0xa4506ceb,0xbef9a3f7,0xc67178f2
};


void sha256_transform(SHA256_CTX *ctx, uchar data[])
{  


   for (i = 0; i < 64; ++i) {
      t1 = h + EP1(e) + CH(e,f,g) + key[i] + m[i];
      t2 = EP0(a) + MAJ(a,b,c);
      h = g;
      g = f;
      f = e;
      e = d + t1;
      d = c;
      c = b;
      b = a;
      a = t1 + t2;
   // do something
   }
```

Comment: If this is a header file, why are there no include guards around it?

Comment: You also need to show either the file which includes the header file, or the header file itself (whichever is not shown).

Comment: You shouldn't put code and global variables in header files. The `key` array is a global variable.

Comment: This problem is impossible to reproduce. Only one declaration of `key` is visible and there are a lot undeclared identifiers. Which .c file caused the error? Please provide some more information. (And make sure, everything irrelevant is eliminated!)

Comment: "i am sure i included this only once" -- Well, that's one underlying cause of your problem; you shouldn't be. You apparently included it in another header file that was included more than once. The other underlying problem is including variable definitions (vs. declarations) in header files; don't do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possibility is that, despite your claims to the contrary, you actually somehow managed to include your header file into two (or more) different translation units. I.e. it is included more than once in the entire program.

(Note that absence of include guards is not to blame in this case. If your header was included more than once into *the same* translation unit, you would have ended up with a wall of compilation errors.)

Another possibility is that something else (not you) is defining another `key` symbol.

Comment: Anyways, found the culprit ! but case wasnt that. Let me explain i put sha256.h in the another header file code.h and function sha256_transform() was being used in code.cpp. Now i put sha256.h in code.cpp and it works great! good but ........... could you throw some light on this

Comment: @User: Describe it in more detail. It is hard to figure out your header inclusion structure from this description. Firstly, how many `.cpp` files does your program involve? Secondly, why is the question tagged [C] but file extension is `.cpp`? The compiler by default treats `.cpp` files as C++ files.

Comment: Befoe code.h contained sha256.h and functions defined in sha256.h used by the source file code.c, didnt work in this scenerio . Now, sha256.h moved to code.cpp and everything looks fine .

Comment: Sorry ! this was .c not cpp

Answer (score 0):

Better way to be sure is to protect your header with an #ifndef. Like follows:

```
#ifndef SHA256_H_
  #define SHA256_H

  ... //Rest of your header
#endif
```